# Where did Gary get these badges from?

Tags: pokemon

In Episode 63 of the Pokémon anime, it can be seen that Gary has ten badges, seven of them unknown.

[image]

The known badges are *Boulder Badge* (top left), the *Cascade Badge* (bottom left), and the *Rainbow Badge* (next to the boulder badge).

Where are the other seven from? And why are there ten of them? Every conference needs eight badges, all of them from the same region.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Besides all the official gyms, there are also unofficial gyms. After beating those, you will also receive a badge. Therefore, I think that those badges were obtained in one or more of the unofficial gyms. The one just right from the top left looks somewhat like the Coal Badge from Sinnoh though.

Unofficial Gyms in the anime:

1. A.J.'s Gym
2. Fighting Spirit Gym
3. Kaz Gym

... and [many more](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gym).

There were 15 gyms in the Kanto region, that is one gym for every type, minus Dark and Steel types. This means they were not featured in the anime/game to prevent confusion, but still are considered official gym's.

> Anyways it would make sense that Ash only went for eight badges compared to a possible 15. Most of his badges in the first season were given to him without even finishing his gym leader battles plus the games only featured eight gyms so then changing it to a higher number in the anime might have been confusing for fans. [Source](http://www.pokecommunity.com/archive/index.php/t-237132.html)

Comment: To enter a League Competition, though, you need to have eight badges from [**official** Gyms](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pokemon_Gyms#Official_Gyms). If all those badges are from unofficial Gyms, then Gary only has three and could not enter.

Comment: @Eric: Maybe he carries more than he shows ... But I'll wait and see if there's another answer.

Comment: @Eric: good point, ill look into is some more in the meanwhile :)

Comment: @looper Found some more information

Comment: I am confused. Are the seven "unknown" badges either unofficial or official gyms? because if three are the same as Ash's and there are 15 official gyms, take out the eight Ash has and we are left with seven unknown official badges, the exact number Gary has. So are they official or unofficial?

Comment: Unofficial gyms were never shown to give out badges as far as I recall.